# How can I validate related fields in api platform?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have question maybe someone could help me with. I tried to find answer, but no results.

Problem:

I have 2 entities Comment and Video, comment belong to video (many to one). When send creation request to /comments with video that no exists, I'm getting next error:

```
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10",
    "title": "An error occurred",
    "detail": "Item not found for resource \"App\\Entity\\Video\" with id \"2\".",
```

and status code 400.

I want change this behavior and receive next response:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10",
    "title": "An error occurred",
    "detail": "Item not found for resource \"App\\Entity\\Video\" with id \"2\".",
    "violations": [
        {
            "propertyPath": "video",
            "message": "Item not found for resource \"App\\Entity\\Video\" with id \"2\".",
            "code": "c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3"
        }
    ]
}
```

and status 422.

Question:

How can I validate related fields?
I already tried create custom validator, but /vendor/api-platform/core/src/Serializer/AbstractItemNormalizer.php return error before my validation.

If you have any solutions for this, I'll really happy. Anyways thank you!

Comment: were you able figure out a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html may help : you just add the validator @Assert\Valid to check if the child exists